# XPATH: How can I reference the child node when the default namespace has been overridden (without using wildcards)

Tags: xml, xpath, namespaces

I'm trying to come up with an XPath expression for the COL node in the following XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="US-ASCII"?>
<RESP
    xmlns="urn:brown.trout.com">
    <QR>
        <COL
            xmlns="urn:child.brown.trout.com">
            <names>Hello</names>
            <names>World</names>
        </COL>
    </QR>
</RESP>
```

The following XPath expression works:

```
/RESP/QR/*:COL
```

However, I'd prefer to have an expression that doesn't use the wildcard (*) character as performance is critical (performance is obviously not an issue for this trivial example - however, it is a concern for the actual application).

There's got to be straightforward way to reference without a wildcard?

Comment: You define a namespace prefix for each namespace and use it in the XPath.  How you define a namespace prefix depends on the hosting language.  See duplicate link for namespace prefix declaration methods of many hosting languages.

Comment: Thank you. This was killing me